# hyperlink with % in it?

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

I need a hyperlink reference with `%` in it. 
Using `\usepackage{hyperref}`
the format
`\href{https://www.wikibooks.org}{Wikibooks home}`
breaks down with a `%` in the url. How to avoid this problem?

Comment: you should be able to use `\%`

Comment: `\bgroup\catcode\`\%=12\href{https://www.foo.bar%baz}{Foobar}\egroup` should work, too.

Comment: See also the manual of the `url` package and in particular its `\urldef` command.

Answer (score 3):

Three comments, three viable solutions: all work, at least with the `pdftex` driver.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{hyperref}

\urldef{\MYurl}\url{http://www.w3.org/file%query}



\begin{document}

See \url{http://www.w3.org/file\%query}.

See \MYurl.

See
\begingroup
    \catcode`\% = 12
    \url{http://www.w3.org/file%query}.
\endgroup

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
\showlists

\end{document}
```

The `\showlists` command will write in the transcript file a description of the internal lists generated by pdfTeX: you can check that the link is always correctly encoded.

**Edit:** As [Heiko Oberdiek remarked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426057/69818), the above is not particulary exciting; more interesting is the fact that all those three solutions, including that based on `\urldef`, work inside the argument of a command too.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{hyperref}

\urldef{\MYurl}\url{http://www.w3.org/file%query}

\newcommand*{\WrapInArgument}[1]{%
    \typeout{}%
    \typeout{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \typeout{}%
    #1%
}



\begin{document}

See \WrapInArgument{\url{http://www.w3.org/file\%query}}.

See \WrapInArgument{\MYurl}.

See
\begingroup
    \catcode`\% = 12
    \WrapInArgument{\url{http://www.w3.org/file%query}}.
\endgroup

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
\showlists

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `\href` or `\url` is not used inside the argument of other macros, then `%` just works, because `hyperref` reads the URL argument verbatim.

However, if `\href` or `\url` are used inside the argument of other commands, the category changes for verbatim category codes come too late, the string is already read by TeX. For this case, some problematic characters like `%` or `#` can be protected by escaping them with the backslash.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \url{http://example.org/a%20b.html}

  \href{http://example.org/a%20b.html}{a b}

  \textbf{\url{http://example.org/a\%20b.html}}

  \textbf{\href{http://example.org/a\%20b.html}{a b}}
\end{document}
```

The PDF file contains the correct URLs:

```
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://example.org/a%20b.html)>>
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://example.org/a%20b.html)>>
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://example.org/a%20b.html)>>
/Subtype/Link/A<</Type/Action/S/URI/URI(http://example.org/a%20b.html)>>
```